# Load lock in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, load, locking

You will see for testing can load pages from the same domain in different browser tabs I have created the following asp code:

```vbs
ahora=now()
do until Datediff("s",ahora,now())>=5
loop
```

You see only thing it does is wait 5s. 
It turns out that if I open a browser, open two tabs and released while two queries to this page, the first 5s takes but the second takes 10s since expects first end to run. Anyone know how to avoid this load lock?

Greetings and thank you very much

Comment: There are probably a couple of solutions to this, but the most obvious would be to make your delay client based using JavaScript.

Comment: The code is just an example to see what the browser, I really want to achieve is that pages are loaded simultaneously in the same browser, whatever your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why classic asp scripts or requests run sequentially for each client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845478/why-classic-asp-scripts-or-requests-run-sequentially-for-each-client)

Comment: It's explained in the accepted answer to the linked question: "Sessions are single threaded and hence pages using sessions can only get processed sequentially".